# Databind a usercontrols DataContext inside a gridview

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm hoping this will be really obvious. I have a list of view models inside an observable collection that I've hooked up to a gridview. The view is complex, with animations and such so I have wrapped it up inside a user control.

My xaml looks like this:-

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles, Mode=OneWay}">                              
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <local:Tile DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

but the tiles data context is always null.

Is there an easy way to get this code working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `DataContext="{Binding}"`. An item's `DataContext` by default is the item from the `ItemsSource` collection.

Comment: still didn't work. And I'm not getting any kind of error in the output window :(

Comment: What is the DataContext of your GridView?

Comment: There isn't one explicitly, so I believe it get's it's context from the page? The Page's data context is set based on the navigation property on the pages LoadState event. This VM contains an observable collection called Tiles containing 8 tile VM's

Comment: There are too many possible issues here. Can you provide a bigger sample? How do you know there are no binding errors? Make sure to change `<local:Tile DataContext="{Binding}" />` to `<local:Tile />`. If the items show up - their DataContext should be set to the item in the ItemsSource collection they represent. You can use `DebugSettings.BindingFailed` event to look for binding errors.

Comment: turned out I had overridden the constructor of the user control and didn't call InitializeComponent - ta!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the `DataContext` is always null? If you were to check it in the constructor of `Tile`, for example, it would be expected to always be null because the binding process doesn't happen until after controls have been instantiated.

`DataContext="{Binding}"` is essentially meaningless, like assigning a local variable to itself in code. It doesn't do anything useful, but also shouldn't harm anything. If you're getting items showing up in your `GridView` and not messing with `DataContext` anywhere inside `Tile` then its `DataContext` will be that item's data.